# Form is not clearing values in success function of $.ajax, using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, forms

I have a form in that, I am using angualr.js. I am binding input values to angular variables. After submitting form, in success function of $.ajax, I am assigning empty values to these variables, but I am seeing same values in form instead of empty strings.
Below is my form code,

```
 <form name="addForm"  ng-submit="outClear()">
      <table>
       <tr>
          <td> <label>Title</label></td>
          <td> <input type="text" id="idTitle" ng-model="Title"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td> <label>Description</label></td>
           <td> <textarea id="idDescription" name="desc" ng-model="Description" ></textarea> </td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" />  </td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Below is my java script code,

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
  MyApp.controller("TicketCntrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.outClear = function () {
    var Title = $scope.Title;
    var Description = $scope.Description;

    var Ticket = {
        "Title": String(Title),
        "Description": String(Description),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Add",
        data: Ticket,
        success: function (data, status) {
        alert('In success');
            $scope.clear();
        },
        error: function (status, error) {
        }
    });


};
$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.Title = '';
    $scope.Description = '';
    alert('In clear');
  }
 }
```

It is going to success function and showing 'In Success' message and going to clear() and assigning '' values to $scope.Title and $scope.Description but in text box and text area I am seeing same values which I have entered.

one more thing I tried, instead of outClear(), I directly call clear() after submitting. Then it is perfectly working(all form values getting empty).

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix angular with jQuery for manipulating scope variables, it will messed up with digest cycle of angular. It will not run digest cycle if you do update `scope` variable from jQuery.

You need to run digest cycle by calling `$apply()` over `$scope` after your method `clear()` in Ajax success to fix it issue quickly, but ideally I wouldn't prefer go for this approach.

Instead do use `$http` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: ah I see... But I need to upload file, with header = Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded. Not sure how to do that with $http.post()

Comment: @vdj4y I'm not sure on that but you could refer this link http://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/angularjs-file-upload-using-http-post-formdata-webapi.htm